# Skybox doesn't render in VR

Tags: three.js, skybox, virtual-reality

I'm playing around with Three.js examples and VR support,
While most examples port well, 
When Skybox is involved it doesn't seems to be ported to VR view.

Init:

```
vrEffect = new THREE.VREffect(renderer, VREffectLoaded);
vrControls = new THREE.VRControls(camera);  
function VREffectLoaded(error) {
    if (error) { 
        console.log("error with init VR : " + error);
    }
}
```

When Rendering

```
if(flags.vrMode===true)
{
    vrControls.update();
    vrEffect.render( scene, camera );
}
else
{
     renderer.render( scene, camera ); 
}
```

I've tried to reload the Skybox mesh onto the scene before the first VR render affect but it didn't help

```
if(flags.vrMode===true)
{
    if(flags.tempFirst === true)
    {
        scene.add( skyBox );
        flags.tempFirst != flags.tempFirst;
    }
    vrControls.update();
    vrEffect.render( scene, camera );
}
else
{
     renderer.render( scene, camera ); 
}
```